# What do those abbreviations mean in Starcraft?

Tags: starcraft-series

A friend of mine asked what some abbreviations in SC mean, and I couldn't answer like

- DT Wall
- Gas the Opponent
- Heavy Metal
- Joyo build
- BCs
- CCMU
- chobo

and a couple of others ... (I'm gonna ask him again, to fill the question with more data)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DT Wall = A wall of Dark Templar, ground troops can't pass without killing them, which they can't do without detection.  Often used on the Utter Darkness mission on Brutal difficulty.

Gas the Opponent = [Gas Steal?](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Gas_Steal)

Heavy Metal = Terran Mech Heavy Build

Joyo build = [A Terran Rush](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/JoyO_Rush) strategy.  Did very well in the 2003 WCG tournament.

BCs = Battle Cruisers

CCMU = Cannot Create More Units (I've always heard this from map makers)

Chobo = [Newb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chobo)

Answer (score 7):

- DT wall is Dark Templar wall (though I'm never sure when that would
  be useful).
- BCs are BattleCruisers.
- Chobo is Korean slang for newbie.
- Heavy Metal would be what I assume to be heavy mech play as a Terran. This is where you focus on building tanks, thors, hellions, banshees, and ravens.
- Gas the Opponent (this is a guess) is an offensive gas steal where
  you build an extractor/assimilator/refinery in your opponents base to
  deny them the ability to mine from it. Thus forcing them down a
  different build path than they would normally go.
- Joyo is a Stracraft: Brood War player, he was famous for a build that would dominate protoss players (http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/JoyO_Rush)
- CCMU = Cannot create more units. It means you've maxed out on your army supply at 200/200.

All these questions seem to be Starcraft: Brood War related. I think it may be mistagged.

Comment: A DT wall, against an opponent that doesn't have detection or AOE, is essentially 100% impenetrable. If you wall in with other units, they can be attacked.

Comment: Google Did You Mean: "youR"? =X

Comment: I re-tagged it as you suggest.

Comment: @Michel I still don't get your comment.